# Laptop does not go to sleep mode nor hibernation

Tags: windows-7, laptop, sleep, hibernate

Whenever I drop down my laptop screen it does not go to the sleep mode nor hibernation. I  went to the "more power options" and then select "choose when to turn off the display" and there I choose sleep for plugged in and hibernate for unplugged. I also tried cmd prompt as administration and use the command "powercfg -HIBERNATE ON" But it still does not work. I've a INTEL ENERGY MANAGEMENT DRIVER installed in my laptop(Lenovo G580 model 20157 with Win7 Ultimate). 
Any suggestions ?

Comment: So the screen does not turn off when the laptop is fully closed?

Comment: cmd -> powercfg -a -> show available sleep states

Comment: Yes #mr._public